# Unity - 2D Character in 3D Environment

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, 2d, sprite

I am making a 3D game in Unity where the player character has to be a 2D sprite. Now, my question is: **what is the best way to implement a 2D object in a 3D environment**?

The character will face the camera and stay centered to the camera. I tried using a mere 2D sprite, but since 2D objects have their own Rigidbody2D class and similar, it simply didn't work out very well with the rest of the game world.

Should I maybe use a plane facing the camera, with the sprite rendered as a material on it? Let me know your thoughts and suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it's completely normal to "put 2D characters in a 3D game".  Just use a quad (as you say, a small plane), and attach a box collider if that is relevant in your game.  As you say, you **don't** use Unity's (excellent) "2D system" for this concept - stick with 3D stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sprites are not restricted from using 3D rigidbody. The only restrictions are for colliders. You can't have both rigidbody and rigidbody2D on one object, you can't have both colliders and colliders2D on object, you can't add colliders2D to 3D rigidbodies and and vice versa. But you totally can add ANY kind of rigidbody or collider to a Sprite.

What kind of game do you make? What genre is it? Is it just a 2D platformer that uses 3D objects? Is it a 3D Action game? Because it is relevant to a kind of physics that you use.

First of all why do you need a rigidbody in the first place? It is needed only if you need a physics to be simulated in your game. If not - you can just write your own movement algorithms for your character and it will be simpler. As I understand it is actually a 3D game like 3D action and camera can move around and character's sprite should always face the camera. Then just separate the game object that simulates physics from the object that holds sprite. Here's an object structure:

CharacterBody (rigidbody, collider)
|
|_CharacterSprite (sprite, component that makes sprite always face the camera)

The ultimate recipe for 3D characters: use capsule collider! Don't care what kind of visual do you use. Don't care if it is a sprite or a model or just a primitive 3D object - use capsule collider! Always.

The opposite is also correct. If you make a 2D game - use ONLY 2D colliders. Even if you are using 3D models. Because when you make a game, it is all about gameplay consistency. The type of graphics doesn't mean anything.

Comment: This answer is too long  :)  It's commonplace to use 2D elements in a fully 3D game.

Comment: This was the solution, but very well explained.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a Quad object and put the sprite as the texture of its material with the cutout rendering mode.
You'll probably to generate a mesh from the sprite if you want proper shadows.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

I created an empty GameObject with a Box Collider and Rigidbody, then put the Sprite as a child object.